# What does this phrase mean?

Tags: expressions

For full context, see here: https://www.docdroid.net/bv19a5D/img-20170817-0001-new.pdf
It is in the very first 5 lines (paragraph 1, example)

それでしたら、こちらのがよろしいんじゃないでしょうか。

I guess the customer simply agrees to buy the recommended bag, but this time I wanted to ask what exactly this huge appendix ...じゃないでしょうか means. It probably is some kind of reaffirmation, I'd like to have some more information on this ^^

Comment: +1 Great question.  Generally, I think you write some very good questions.  It's clear that you're gaining increasing mastery of grammatical points.  Also, it seems that you're usually very apt at honing in on exactly what point of grammar is at issue.  I'd like to suggest that, because of these strengths of yours, you rethink the subject lines for your questions to better reflect the content.  That will help future users in their search for answers.  For example, you might make the title of this posting something like, "Can じゃないでしょうか as a tag question be used for reaffirmation?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> それでしたら、こちらのがよろしいん**じゃないでしょうか**。

I would interpret "それでしたら" as "それがお好{す}きなら/それがお好｛この｝みでしたら" or "そのようなものがお好｛す｝きなら/そのようなものがお好｛この｝みでしたら", then the part will be interpreted into like "If your preference is like that".

The huge appendix is changed gradually as:

1. こちらのがよろしい**ん**じゃないでしょうか。euphonic change from 1 to 2
2. こちらの方がよろしい**の**じゃないでしょうか。
   こちらの方がよろしいの**じゃ**ないでしょうか。euphonic change from 2 to 3
3. こちらの方がよろしいの**では**ないでしょうか。
   こちらの方がよろしいのではない**でしょうか**。 polite form 3 to normal form 4
4. こちらの方がよろしいのではない**か**。
   = こちらの方がよろしい + **の** + ではないか (let's do (something) )。
   **の** in 4 is a particle used to nominalizes verbs and adjectives​

The whole sentence will be like:
*If your preference is like that, I think that this one is better, don't you think so?*

Answer (score 2):

It's a form of a question that elicits some form of confirmation.

> お寿司は日本の代表的な料理だと言えるんじゃないでしょうか。
>   
> Sushi is the delicacy that best represents Japan, wouldn't you say?

You may not have the full proof to back up the statement you are posing and hence you are seeking some form of confirmation from your listener/reader.